# Set an active class for magento2.1 wishlist

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I can add product to my Wish-list on product page `Magnnto2.1`, but after refresh the product page,I want to see this product already added to wish-list by changing color of wish-list icon (set active class for example)
what should i do if anyone idea share with me?

Comment: Any new answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace content of

> /app/design/frontend/Dapl/demo/Magento_Wishlist/templates/catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml

with

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist $block */
?>
<?php if ($block->isWishListAllowed()) : ?>
    <?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
    <?php $isAdded = $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getWishlistItemCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $_product->getId())->count(); ?>
    <?php if($isAdded): ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="action towishlist already-added" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Added to Wish List')) ?></span></a>
    <?php else: ?>
       <a href="#" class="action towishlist" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWishlistParams() ?>' data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "body": {
            "addToWishlist": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getWishlistOptionsJson() ?>
        }
    }
</script>
```

then add below code to your custom css file

> .product-social-links .action.towishlist.already-added{color: red;}